# onSuggestionClick(int position) in SuggestionListener gives absolute position of ArrayList

Tags: java, android

My code is:

```
    ArrayList<String> autocompleteArray = new ArrayList<>();

    autocompleteArray.add("apple");
    autocompleteArray.add("apples");
    autocompleteArray.add("banana");
    autocompleteArray.add("bananas");
    autocompleteArray.add("orange");

    SearchView.SearchAutoComplete searchAutoComplete = searchView.findViewById(android.support.v7.appcompat.R.id.search_src_text);
    searchAutoComplete.setDropDownAnchor(R.id.main_toolbar);
    searchAutoComplete.setThreshold(1);`searchAutoComplete.setDropDownAnchor(R.id.main_toolbar);
    searchAutoComplete.setThreshold(1);`
    final ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(getActivity(), R.layout.search_autocomplete, autocompleteArray);
    searchAutoComplete.setAdapter(adapter);

    searchView.setOnSuggestionListener(new SearchView.OnSuggestionListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onSuggestionSelect(int position) {

            Log.i("search_tag",autocompleteArray.get(position));
            searchView.setQuery(autocompleteArray.get(position),true);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onSuggestionClick(int position) {
            Log.i("search_tag",autocompleteArray.get(position));
            searchView.setQuery(autocompleteArray.get(position),true);
            return true;
        }
    });
```

When I click on *apple*, the output in log is *"apple"* ,*"apples"* when I click on *apples*.

But when I type *"ba"* only *"banana"* and *"bananas"* is shown[as expexted] and when i click on *"banana"* ,*"apple"* is the output and also when i click on *"bananas"* , *"apples"* is the output. It seems like "position" is giving the absolute position in arraylist and not the filtered array.

How can I get the position of the filtered arraylist?

Comment: Instead of adding suggestionListener try this `searchAutoComplete.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {
                String queryString = (String)adapterView.getItemAtPosition(position);
                searchView.setQuery(queryString,true);
                Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "item clicked " + queryString, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });`

Comment: Thanks! this solved my problem.

Comment: Awesome !, now I am posting it as a answer so that nobody else need to put the same effort.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of adding `suggestionListener` try below

```
    searchAutoComplete.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {
            String queryString = (String)adapterView.getItemAtPosition(position);
            searchView.setQuery(queryString,true);
            Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "item clicked " + queryString, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

According to the documentation, the position is absolute
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SearchView.OnSuggestionListener.html#onSuggestionClick(int)

In order to use the data, check below example

```
searchView.setOnSuggestionListener(new SearchView.OnSuggestionListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onSuggestionSelect(int position) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSuggestionClick(int position) {
        Cursor cursor= searchView.getSuggestionsAdapter().getCursor();
        cursor.moveToPosition(position);
        String suggestion =cursor.getString(2);//2 is the index of col containing suggestion name.
        searchView.setQuery(suggestion,true);//setting suggestion
        return true;
    }
});
```

Comment: already tried this and the app crashed with the error        "java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.database.Cursor android.support.v4.widget.CursorAdapter.getCursor()' on a null object reference" on the line that declares the Cursor

Comment: Can you post the code after using the cursor adapter. It'll help us find the issue faster

Comment: I replaced my onSuggestionClick() with your function. Thats the only change I made to the original code